# pin a layout and unpin on scroll

Tags: android

hi i have an product details activity all of my elements are static and stay still but i have an button (Add to card) i want to when im in the details of the product button scroll with me but when i end the product details button stay at the end of details then scroll down without button for the related items and comments how can i do it i will explain by an example if you used Telegram messenger app before you can see the date of the day message sent to you but when you scroll up on the older posts you can see at the start of the message sent the date will pin and stay there please see this pictures sorry if i cant explain well please ask me !
[image: on The day message sent to you] and this is [image: on the start of that day]

Answer (score 0):

you can attach ItemDecoration to your recyclerView and override onDraw method and use some logic to draw what you want on the recyclerView base on your recyclerView item position and your data

```
 recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            super.onDraw(c, parent, state);
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        }
    });
```

Comment: salam aziz agha bbein man az ScrollView estefade mikonam alan tasmim daram check konam bebinam onjayie ke gharare dokme gharar begire 100 darsad visible hast ya na agar visible bood in 1 kiyo visibilty sho Gone mikonam va mizaramesh toye fazaye khali @Amir Hossein Mirzaei

Comment: be nazaret in rah doroste? chejori bas befahmam layout kamelan visible hast?

Comment: @razaAmini ino bebin https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/89017111?noredirect=1

Comment: dadash anjamesh dadam hamonjor ke gofftam age khasi sourcesho bet bedam khyli ghashang shod damet garm <3